# Issue regarding error of non class type?

Tags: c++, types, compiler-errors, concatenation

i am new to c++ and i have been trying to deal with concatenation of inputs. i have a user input first name and last name and last four digits of a fake social security. i then want to add them all together by takinng the first letter of the first name, first letter of last name, and the four numbers. everytime i run my program an error pops up for non class type.
Error:

```
In function 'int main()': 89:26: error: request for member 'at' in 'firstname[i]', which is of non-class type 'string2 {aka char [3]}' 90:26: error: request for member 'at' in 'lastname[i]', which is of non-c`enter code here`lass type 'string2 {aka char [3]}' 
typedef char string2[size];
string2 firstname[size];
string2 lastname[size];
string2 middleinitial[size];
string2 lastfour[size];


//CONCATINATION FOR ID
string id[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++)
{
   id [i] = firstname[i].at (0);//set id = to first letter of the first name
   id [i] += lastname[i].at (1);//concatinate the first letter of the last name to the id
   id [i] += lastfour[i]; //concatinate the last four 
}
```

Comment: Try `firstname[i][0]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The variables you are using are all declared as `char[][]`. To use `at()`, you need to opt for `std::string` since it is a member function of that class.

Alternatively, you can access the `i`th character of the `j`th entry by using `operator[]`, like, `firstname[j].[i]`.